# Swiftui items get duplicated in all views when added to a single custom view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, view

I'm struggling with the following issue: I'm trying to build a very simple app that lets you add items in a dedicated view that can be collapsed. I managed to write a simple function that lets me add multiple of these custom collapsable views. It's my first app so I wanted to follow the MVVM protocol. I think I got confused along the way because now every item I add gets automatically added to all the custom collapsable views I made. Is there any way to fix this? I thought using the UUID would solve this issue.. I'm guessing that I have to customise the "saveButtonPressed" function, but I don't know how to tell it to only add the item to the view where I pressed the "plus" button..

### Here are the Models for the individual items and the collapsable view:

```
struct ItemModel: Identifiable, Equatable {
let id: String
let title: String

init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title

 }

  func updateCompletion() -> ItemModel {
  return ItemModel(id: id, title: title)
   }
   }
```

--

```
import Foundation

struct CollapsableItem: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
let id: String
var title: String

init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title

    
}

    func updateCompletion() -> CollapsableItem {
return CollapsableItem(id: id, title: title)
    }
}
```

### These are my two ViewModels:

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject  {
@Published var items: [ItemModel] = []

init() {
    getItems()
}

func getItems() {
    let newItems = [
        ItemModel(title: "List Item1"),
        ItemModel(title: "List Item2"),
        ItemModel(title: "List Item3"),
    ]
    items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
    }

func addItem(title: String) {
    let newItem = ItemModel(title: title)
    items.append(newItem)
}

func updateItem(item: ItemModel) {
    
    if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id}) {
        items[index] = item.updateCompletion()
    }
    }
    }
```

--

```
class CollapsedViewModel: ObservableObject  {
@Published var collapsableItems: [CollapsableItem] = []

@Published var id = UUID().uuidString


init() {
    getCollapsableItems()
}


func getCollapsableItems() {
    let newCollapsableItems = [
        CollapsableItem(title: "Wake up")
    ]
    collapsableItems.append(contentsOf: newCollapsableItems)
}

func addCollapsableItem(title: String) {
    let newCollapsableItem = CollapsableItem(title: title)
    collapsableItems.append(newCollapsableItem)
}




func updateCollapsableItem(collapsableItem: CollapsableItem) {
    
    if let index = collapsableItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == 
collapsableItem.id}) {
        collapsableItems[index] = 
 collapsableItem.updateCompletion()
    }
}

 }
```

### The item view:

```
struct ListRowView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
let item: ItemModel

var body: some View {
    HStack() {

        
        Text(item.title)
            .font(.body)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .frame(width: 232, height: 16)

        
    }
    .padding( )
    .frame(width: 396, height: 56)
    .background(.gray)
    .cornerRadius(12.0)

}
}
```

### The collapsable view:

```
struct CollapsedView2<Content: View>: View {
@State var collapsableItem: CollapsableItem
@EnvironmentObject var collapsedViewModel: CollapsedViewModel
@State private var collapsed: Bool = true
@EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
@State var label: () -> Text
@State var content: () -> Content
@State private var show = true

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Button(
                    action: { self.collapsed.toggle() },
                    label: {
                        HStack() {
                            Text("Hello")
                                .font(.title2.bold())
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: self.collapsed ? "chevron.down" : 
                       "chevron.up")
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.01))
                    }
                )
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                
                Button(action: saveButtonPressed, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                })
            }
            VStack {
                self.content()
            }
            
            ForEach(listViewModel.items) { item in ListRowView (item: item)
                
            }
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            .frame(minWidth: 396, maxWidth: 396, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 
            0 : .none)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: show)
            .clipped()
            .transition(.slide)
            
        }
    }
    
}
func saveButtonPressed() {
    listViewModel.addItem(title: "Hello")
}
        }
```

### and finally the main view:

```
struct ListView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
@EnvironmentObject var collapsedViewModel: CollapsedViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("MyFirstApp")
                            .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                        
                        Button(action: newCollapsablePressed, label: {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                        })
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.leading)
                    
                    ForEach(collapsedViewModel.collapsableItems) { collapsableItem in 
                    CollapsedView2 (collapsableItem: collapsableItem,                      
                    label: { Text("") .font(.title2.bold()) },
                                                                                                      
                    content: {
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("")
                            Spacer() }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        
                        
                    })
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .statusBar(hidden: false)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
}

func newCollapsablePressed() {
    collapsedViewModel.addCollapsableItem(title: "hello2")
}
}
```

Would love to understand how I could fix this!

Comment: I think you forgot show CollapsedViewModel code?

Comment: Oh - I forgot, my bad. It should be there now.

Comment: Are you trying to display hierarchical data in a list?

Comment: I am a bit lost in your description. Which part seems to be the problem? `save item` or `save collapse`? Which view shows the wrong data? `ItemView` or `CollapseView`?

Comment: Is your data hierarchical, example folders in file system. A folder can have child folders (child items)?

Comment: The "save item" is the problem. In the version above I can without any issues add another "collapsable item" that is unique and not the same as the original one. However, all the ItemView items are added to both lists, when they should only be added to the one where you pressed the "plus" button.

Comment: And the data isn't hierarchical, it's just random items in a list like view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the anwser for your comment about add item in each CollapsedView2.
Because ListViewModel is not ObservableObject (ListViewModel is difference from each CollapsableItem). You should use "@State var items: [ItemModel]".

```
struct CollapsedView2<Content: View>: View {
    @State var collapsableItem: CollapsableItem
//    @State var listViewModel = ListViewModel()
    @State var collapsed: Bool = true
    @State var label: () -> Text
    @State var content: () -> Content
    @State private var show = true
    @State var items: [ItemModel] = []
    @State var count = 1

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Text("Hello")
                        .font(.title2.bold())
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button( action: { self.collapsed.toggle() },
                            label: {
                        Image(systemName: self.collapsed ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
                    }
                    )
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                    Button(action: saveButtonPressed, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.title2)
//                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
                VStack {
                    self.content()
                }

                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ListRowView (item: item)
                }
                .lineLimit(1)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: show)
                .clipped()
                .transition(.slide)
            }
    }

    func saveButtonPressed() {
        addItem(title: "Hello \(count)")
        count += 1
    }
    
    func addItem(title: String) {
        let newItem = ItemModel(title: title)
        items.append(newItem)
    }

    func updateItem(item: ItemModel) {

        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id}) {
            items[index] = item.updateCompletion()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question came to my mind just now: If I want to make a dedicated view that lets me customise the "saveButtonPressed" function (f.e. a navigation link to another view that has a textfield and save button for adding items to the list) how would I pass the items between the views? Would I just @State var items: [ItemModel] = [] in the new view again?

Comment: or would I state them in the Navigation Link destination like this @State items: CollapsedView2.items?

Comment: you can use "Binding" to pass the items between the views

Answer (score 0):

There is the anwser. Ask me if you have some questions

```
struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var collapsedViewModel = CollapsedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("MyFirstApp")
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                    
                    Button(action: newCollapsablePressed, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.title2)
//                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
                
                ForEach(collapsedViewModel.collapsableItems) { collapsableItem in
                    CollapsedView2 (collapsableItem: collapsableItem,
                                    label: { Text("") .font(.title2.bold()) },
                                    content: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .statusBar(hidden: false)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    
    func newCollapsablePressed() {
        collapsedViewModel.addCollapsableItem(title: "hello2")
    }
}

struct CollapsedView2<Content: View>: View {
    @State var collapsableItem: CollapsableItem
    @State var listViewModel = ListViewModel()
    @State var collapsed: Bool = true
    @State var label: () -> Text
    @State var content: () -> Content
    @State private var show = true
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Button( action: { self.collapsed.toggle() },
                            label: {
                        HStack() {
                            Text("Hello")
                                .font(.title2.bold())
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: self.collapsed ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.01))
                    }
                    )
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    
                    Button(action: saveButtonPressed, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
                VStack {
                    self.content()
                }
                
                ForEach(listViewModel.items) { item in
                    ListRowView (item: item)
                }
                .lineLimit(1)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: show)
                .clipped()
                .transition(.slide)
            }
    }
    
    func saveButtonPressed() {
        listViewModel.addItem(title: "Hello")
    }
}

struct ListRowView: View {
    let item: ItemModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text(item.title)
                .font(.body)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .frame(width: 232, height: 16)
        }
        .padding( )
        .frame(width: 396, height: 56)
        .background(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(12.0)
        
    }
}

class ListViewModel {
    var items: [ItemModel] = []
    
    init() {
        getItems()
    }
    
    func getItems() {
        let newItems = [
            ItemModel(title: "List Item1"),
            ItemModel(title: "List Item2"),
            ItemModel(title: "List Item3"),
        ]
        items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
    }
    
    func addItem(title: String) {
        let newItem = ItemModel(title: title)
        items.append(newItem)
    }
    
    func updateItem(item: ItemModel) {
        
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id}) {
            items[index] = item.updateCompletion()
        }
    }
}

class CollapsedViewModel: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var collapsableItems: [CollapsableItem] = []
    
    @Published var id = UUID().uuidString
    
    
    init() {
        getCollapsableItems()
    }
    
    
    func getCollapsableItems() {
        let newCollapsableItems = [
            CollapsableItem(title: "Wake up")
        ]
        collapsableItems.append(contentsOf: newCollapsableItems)
    }
    
    func addCollapsableItem(title: String) {
        let newCollapsableItem = CollapsableItem(title: title)
        collapsableItems.append(newCollapsableItem)
    }
    
    func updateCollapsableItem(collapsableItem: CollapsableItem) {
        
        if let index = collapsableItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id ==
            collapsableItem.id}) {
            collapsableItems[index] =
            collapsableItem.updateCompletion()
        }
    }
    
}

struct CollapsableItem: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    var title: String
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
    
    func updateCompletion() -> CollapsableItem {
        return CollapsableItem(id: id, title: title)
    }
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, title: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        
    }
    
    func updateCompletion() -> ItemModel {
        return ItemModel(id: id, title: title)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, pls dont use "EnvironmentObject" everywhere :v

Comment: Second, ListViewModel is difference from each CollapsableItem, so you shouldnt use "@Published" for items in ListViewModel.

Comment: and you can use diffchecker .com to check file by file

Comment: First of all, thank you so much - it was such a pain not being able to solve this when it should be a really easy problem to fix lol. It works now! The only thing I noticed is, that when you press the plus button in one collapsed list, the added item only appear after you add another collapsable List using the other plus button...